# Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'U'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have these below types declaried,

```
import { ReadonlyDeep } from 'type-fest';
import { AsyncFunction } from 'type-fest/source/async-return-type';

// We don't allow null. undefined is required instead.
export type SimpleArgs = (string | number | boolean | undefined)[];

export type BasicAsyncFunc<U extends SimpleArgs, R> = (...args: U) => Promise<ReadonlyDeep<R>>;

interface Memoized<U extends SimpleArgs, R> extends BasicAsyncFunc<U, R> {
  cache_size: () => number;
  clear_cache: () => void;
}


const memoize_async = <R, U extends SimpleArgs>(
  options: { ttl: number; size: number },
  f: BasicAsyncFunc<U, R>,
): Memoized<U, R> => {
  return () => {
     // some more logic
     return f(arg) // error is here
  }
}
```

> Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'U'.
> '[string]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(string | number | boolean | undefined)[]'.

*Also, please can anyone explain the type declared above?*

*What is the signature of `f` from the above type?*

*Also, the signature of `memoize_async`?*

I have a basic understanding of generics. I am confused here.

I tried as bellow,

1. `export type SimpleArgs = (string | number | boolean | undefined)[];`

- type `SimpleArgs` should be an array of string or number or boolean and undefined is also allowed.

2. `export type BasicAsyncFunc<U extends SimpleArgs, R> = (...args: U) => Promise<ReadonlyDeep<R>>;`

   `BasicAsyncFunc` type accepts two generics:

   - U, extends `SimpleArgs` *What U can be here?*
   - What is `R` here?
3. `interface Memoized<U extends SimpleArgs, R> extends BasicAsyncFunc<U, R> { cache_size: () => number; clear_cache: () => void; }`

   No idea at all here :(

Comment: can you show how `arg` is defined ?

Comment: `args` is just a string  path `./fileName.js`

Comment: how your function is supposed to deal with a string when your function can be : `add(int, int)` ?

Comment: when I write `memoize_async({ttl:1, size:1}, (a: number)=>a.toFixed())()` I will get a runtime error

Comment: Just explain the types. I will deal with other params.

Answer (score 1):

My best answer is that `U` in `memoized_async` is not actually `(string | number | boolean | undefined)[]`.

If I did this:

```
const foo = memoize_async<void,number[]>({ttl:0,size:0},async ()=>{
  
})
```

`arg`, which is apparently a string, would be invalid because the function expects a number. I'm not exactly sure what you would need to do as a quick fix but if I were you I would just slap a bunch of @ts-ignore's or type assertions to fix the job.